# Callback failing if contains ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add a callback to a pre existing function in the jquery plugin nitelite https://github.com/premasagar/nitelite - The callback works fine http://jsfiddle.net/HPc4e/2/ - unless I have ajax in the callback?

Appropriate section of close function:

```
// Blah blah ...

else {

    showFlash();

    this.overlay.remove();

    this.container
        .empty()
        .remove();

    $(this).triggerHandler('close');

    // Add callback
    if (typeof callback == "function") {
        callback();
    }

}
return this;
```

Callback:

```
lb.close(undefined, 'click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: {submit: $(this).val()},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            lightbox('Lightbox 2', '<p>Oh hi</p>', 'lightbox2');
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: can you put up a demo (jsfiddle.net ?) showing the behaviour?  .empty and .remove shouldn't return until after the DOM has been updated.

Comment: Oh crap my demo works : / http://jsfiddle.net/HPc4e/2/

Comment: Edited question as it works fine - unless callback contains ajax!?

Comment: You mean if there is  no ajax request you want the callback

Comment: No the callback is ajax, it gets content from a controller and then uses the content to create a lightbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that your callback is throwing an exception.

What is the value of `this` supposed to be when it's invoked?  Are you sure it's pointing at a jQuery compatible element that has a `.val()` method?

Comment: Hmm maybe - but removing `data: {submit: $(this).val()},` doesn't have any effect.

Comment: It was throwing an exception - bad url. Thanks